# attempt to display RSI values across timeframes

Tags: trading, rsi

My main objective is to display RSI of day, week and month across TF. While it comes correctly sometimes but when I move from day to week to month, the RSI of day displays incorrectly.

part of code is given below: I can share entire code if required.

```
myPeriod = input.int(defval=13, title='Period')
src = input(close)
myRSI = ta.rsi(src, myPeriod)

rsi_day = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", myRSI)
rsi_week = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", myRSI)
rsi_mth = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", myRSI)

if(timeframe.period == "D")
table.cell(trendtable, 2, 2, text = str.tostring(math.round(rsi_day,2)), bgcolor = color.black, text_color=color.red) 
table.cell(trendtable, 3, 2, text = str.tostring(math.round(wma_day,2)), bgcolor = color.black, text_color=color.blue)
table.cell(trendtable, 4, 2, text = str.tostring(math.round(ema_day,2)), bgcolor = color.black, text_color=color.green)
```